Apache Airflow giving Broken DAG
Apache Airflow giving broken DAG and can't seem to retrieve information from my dbt-dag.py
Error Code:
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt-dag.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/cosmos/operators/base.py", line 361, in __init__
    self.full_refresh = full_refresh
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1198, in __setattr__
    if key in self.__init_kwargs:
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'DbtRunLocalOperator' object has no attribute '_BaseOperator__init_kwargs'. Did you mean: '_BaseOperator__instantiated'?

Code for dbt-dag.py
import os
from datetime import datetime

from cosmos import DbtDag, ProfileConfig, ProjectConfig, ExecutionConfig
from cosmos.profiles import SnowflakeUserPasswordProfileMapping

profile_config = ProfileConfig(
    profile_name='default',
    target_name='dev',
    profile_mapping=SnowflakeUserPasswordProfileMapping(
        conn_id='snowflake_conn',
        profile_args={'database':'dbt_db','schema':'dbt_schema'},
    )
)

dbt_snowflake_dag = DbtDag(
    project_config=ProjectConfig('/usr/local/airflow/dags/dbt/data_pipeline',),
    operator_args={'install_deps':True},
    profile_config=profile_config,
    execution_config=ExecutionConfig(dbt_executable_path=f"{os.environ['AIRFLOW_HOME']}/dbt_venv/bin/dbt",),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    start_date=datetime(2023, 9, 10),
    catchup=False,
    dag_id="dbt_dag",

I have followed some youtube tutorial and tried to follow along but can't seem to make it work and it seem like it is working for others.

Could you also share code snippet for DbtDag? Bz for now it's not enough code to review

sorry but that is the entire code inside the dbt-dag.py other than that the rest are inside the data_pipeline

Could you share that code then?

Hi sorry for late response but I was following this youtube video as a guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLXkGB7krGo

I had the same issue today, I think it comes from cosmos package. If you just want to try I suggested you use another Execution Modes (see more details in astronomer-cosmos documentation https://astronomer.github.io/astronomer-cosmos/getting_started/astro.html, https://astronomer.github.io/astronomer-cosmos/getting_started/execution-modes.html)
I was able to fix my problem by replacing this part of the code
execution_config=ExecutionConfig(dbt_executable_path=f"{os.environ['AIRFLOW_HOME']}/dbt_venv/bin/dbt",),

by this snippet:
execution_config=ExecutionConfig(
        execution_mode=ExecutionMode.VIRTUALENV,
    ),
    operator_args={
        "py_system_site_packages": False,
        "py_requirements": ["dbt-bigquery==1.7.4"]
    },

Please don't forget to change the dbt-adapter, hope it helps.
